# How to get login credentials in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I made a hook by implementing `login.jsp` inside `/html/portlet/login` folder.
Now I tried to get the login credentials submitted through the default login form. The code which I tried is:-

```
request.getParameter("login")
```

but it could not retrieve login credential so I want to ask how to retrieve login credential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get username and password by using following  ways:

```
String username = themeDisplay.getUser().getScreenName();

String password = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(WebKeys.USER_PASSWORD);
```

and write the below lines  in **portal-ext.properties:**

```
session.store.password=true

session.shared.attributes.excludes=
```

But you need to take the precaution because when you use session.store.password=true  then passwords will be stored n clear text and the same will be appear in dumps.

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: what to write inside session.shared.attributes.excludes=

Comment: dont write anything.. keep it as it is

Comment: ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)RenderRequest .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
use this to get object

Comment: i am getting password correctly but not username as I could not use RenderRequest in my code since only HttpServletRequest reference is there. Is there any alternative of using themedisplay?

Comment: use your request object directly.. You can get themedisplay  from any request object